# Apple Mach -O Linker Error Cocos2d-x

Tags: ios, xcode, cocos2d-iphone

Hello i encountered this problem and have been searching for hours trying to find the solution for this problem.

```
 "cocos2d::CCObject::retainCount() const", referenced from:
  cocos2d::extension::CCDisplayManager::~CCDisplayManager() in CCDisplayManager.o
  cocos2d::extension::CCDisplayManager::~CCDisplayManager() in CCDisplayManager.o
  cocos2d::extension::CCDisplayManager::~CCDisplayManager() in CCDisplayManager.o
  cocos2d::CCTextureCache::removeUnusedTextures() in libcocos2dx.a(CCTextureCache.o)
  cocos2d::CCTextureCache::dumpCachedTextureInfo() in libcocos2dx.a(CCTextureCache.o)
  ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
```

And about 12 more of similar problem.

I'm using xcode 4.6, 
I have tried a couple of solution:

- Remove i386 architecture from "Valid Architecture" in both my project and my cocos2d-x sub-project,
- Set "Build Active Architecture Only" to YES
- Delete Data location of my project from iphone simulator or from xcode derrived data location
- Restart Xcode
- Restart Mac

Still, none of these solution has worked for me. Here's my suspicion about this error

- I did switching xcode data location from "unique"-"legacy"
- Because I tend to save my daily project to folder, the derrived data location in xcode may have same name, each concatenate with some unique name

Does anyone have any idea how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I did switching xcode data location from "unique"-"legacy"

Don't do that! The legacy option is there only for legacy projects that absolutely require it due to their setup/structure and where updating the project is not possible or not desirable. In all other cases the legacy build location setting just tends to cause problems, like the one you have.

Unless you have a very, very good reason and understand the implications of changing the build location, leave it set to the default *Unique*. Otherwise use either Shared or Custom but never Legacy.

Comment: Thanks! I guess i will rebuild my project from beginning because of that.